# Git retrieve a file from commits without overwriting

Tags: git

Is there a way to retrieve a single or multiple files from previous commits without overwriting my current changes. What I mean is if there is a native way to retrieve an entire file and save it at some directory. I know I can accomplish this with stashes, but I am hoping for a much simpler way.

Comment: should there be a space between `--` and `myfile`?

Comment: Yep, fixed, sorry about that

Comment: I get nothing. Hm. Here is an example `git show 21237cc0f27d3705c60144f7a30fc5293e55680f -- welcome.blade.php`

Comment: Because I got it wrong. Hang on a sec

Comment: Got it, see answer. I think I need to lie down now.

Comment: I'm sure there's more than one way, that's just the one I know. Except I forgot what I knew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it....

```
git show 21237cc:welcome.blade.php > /tmp/welcome.blade.php
```